# Why have people's wishes become so powerful after God vanished?

Tags: sunday-without-god

In the anime, several wishes are in place, from creating alternate realities (Alice, Dee), to immortality (Humpnie) and absolute life or death (Ulla, Celica).

Why are people's wishes so powerful? Were they like that before God vanished?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, yes. Throughout the series, it is mentioned that the reason humans can actually live they way they can is because God has given them their "wish". The reason for the immortality (even if it is miserable) is because God has given up on them and given the human beings what they desired. (Even if it's not a great idea...)

So, this whole thing became possible because of the humans wishes and what they thought was best. So, since this happened before "God" vanished (or as God did, that is) it's safe to assume that perhaps God was capable of fulfilling a few things here and there, too.

This is just speculation but perhaps God has not abandoned them completely just yet.